# Dimension of the ring $k[x,y]/(xy-1)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Question: $\dim k[x,y]/(xy-1) = ?$

Let $Z$ be a plain curve $y=x^2$ over a fixed algebraic closed field $k$, the zero set of a polynomial $f=y-x^2$.
Then we obtain the affine coordinate ring $A(Z):= k[x,y]/(xy-1)$. Then show that the dimension of $A(Z)$.

Def:
In a ring $A$, the height of a prime ideal $p$ is the supremum of all integer $n$ such that there exists a chain $p_0 \subset p_1 \subset p_2 \subset \cdots \subset p_n=p$ of distinct prime ideals.

Def
We define the dimension of a ring $A$ to be the supremum of the heights of all prime ideals.

My answer:

$k[x,y]/(xy-1) = k[x] + k[y]:=\{f+g; f\in k[x], g \in k[y] \}$.

I cannot reveal how to make a prime ideal sequence.

Comment: Do you know what $\dim k[x, y]$ is and what its maximal ideals look like?

Comment: If $Z$ is the plane curve $y=x^2$, we do not have $A(Z)=k[x,y]/(xy-1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of solving it. Let $H$ be the hyperbola $xy=1$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$. The dimension of its coordinate ring $k[x,y]/(xy-1)$ is the dimension of $H$.

In turn, $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus {0}$ via the map $p: H \to \mathbb{A}^1 \setminus {0}$ defined by $p(x,y)=x$, whose inverse is $p^{-1}(t)=(t,1/t)$ (if you are not familiar with the notion of isomorphism yet, just replace it by homeomorphism in this case).

In particular $H$ and $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus {0}$ have same dimension. Since the latter is an open subset of $\mathbb{A}^1$ we get

$$\dim \frac{k[x,y]}{(xy-1)}=\dim H=\dim \mathbb{A}^1 \setminus {0}=\dim \mathbb{A}^1=1.$$

Comment: Because the dimension of topological space is defined using only topological structure, the dimension is topological invariant. Thus to calculate the dimension, we can transfer our argument to $\mathbb{A}-0$. Because any irreducible closed subset of  $\mathbb{A}$ is a point, and thus  closed subset of $\mathbb{A}$ is also a point.   Hence dim $\mathbb{A}-0=1$.  I am not sure what the isomorphic mean. The definition of dimension depends on the topological structure only so, I guess it is sufficient to consider the homeomorphism only.

Comment: Indeed. The notion of dimension is purely topological so it is preserved under homeomorphisms. In our case $p$ is a homeomorphism between $H$ and $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{0\}$ (forget about isomorphisms). The argument to compute the dimension of $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{0\}$ is also perfectly correct (you could also use that we know $\dim \mathbb{A}^1=1$ and and the fact that every nonempty open subset of an affine variety has the dimension of the variety).

Answer (score 2):

The zero-set of $xy-1$ is an hyperbola, hence we have to expect that the dimension is $1$.

Note that $xy-1$ is irreducible, so it generates a prime ideal which is not maximal since there are elements that do not become invertible in the quotient (e.g. $x-1$).

The prime ideals in the quotient are in bijection with the prime ideals in $k[x,y]$ containing $(xy-1)$. Since we know that $k[x,y]$ has dimension $2$, the quotient $A$ must have dimension $1$. Explicitely, the maximal ideals are of the form
$$
(x-a,y-b)\qquad\text{with $ab=1$.}
$$

Comment: Why dim$k[x,y]=2$ implies dim $A=1$ ? The existence of the prime ideal $(xy-1)$ and the bijection of prime ideals between the polynomial ring and the quotient implies that dim $A  \leq 1$ , but I cannot exclude the case that  dim $A  =0.$ Intuitively I can understand that the element $x-1$ in the quotient is not invertible because the inverse of $x-1$  is given by the geometric series which is not a polynomial  but I cannot logically prove it.

Comment: @JeanBillie: I'll give you two hints. (1) The ideal $I=(x-1,y-1)$ is maximal in $k[x,y]$. (2) $I\supseteq(xy-1)$. Bonus hint: $(1,1)$ is a point on the hyperbola $xy=1$.

Comment: Because dim $k[x,y]=2$, the sequence $0 \subset  (xy-1) \subset (x-1,y-1)$ in   $k[x,y]$   has the maximal height 2. This sequence has height 1 in the coordinate ring $k[x,y]/(xy-1)$. Because dim is the supremum of  heights, such sequence implies dim $k[x,y]/(xy-1) \geq 1$.  If dim $k[x,y]/(xy-1)=2$, then there is a sequence of distinct prime ideals $ 0 \subset (xy-1) \subset p_2 \subset p _3$ in $k[x,y]$, but this contradicts that 
 dim $k[x,y]=2$. Thus,  dim $k[x,y]/(xy-1)=1$. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @JeanBillie: you are welcome. The rule of thumb is this: if $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ is an irreducible polynomial the quotient $A=k[x_1,...,x_n]/(f)$ is the ring of algebraic function on the zero locus $V=V(f=0)$. Then the prime ideals of $A$ correspond to irreducible algebraic subsets of $V$. In the case in question $n=2$ so $V$ is a curve (in fact an hyperbola) and the only algebraic irreducible subsets os a curve are its points.